# Printing frequency of words in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and I'm currently writing a program to display words given by user input and the frequency of the words. I believe I have all the functions set properly I am just having trouble displaying the words and their frequency (I believe it has to do with my hash values). 
An example of an input would be : hello hello how are are you.
and I'd like it to be displayed as: hello = 2 how = 1 are = 2 you = 1

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w 
 use strict;
 my @User_Input = <STDIN>;
 chomp(@User_Input);

 my $Word;
 my $Word_Count = 0;
 my %Word_Hash;

foreach $Word (@User_Input)
{
        #body of loop

         my @lines = split(/\s+/, $Word);
         $Word_Count = scalar(@lines);

        if (exists($Word_Hash{$Word}))
        {
                keys(%Word_Hash);
                my @all_words = keys(%Word_Hash);

        }

}
```

Comment: I'm confused by the `if` statement there.  You're never storing anything in the hash, just checking whether it's already in the hash, and then calling `keys` a couple of times (which is how you'd get all the words back out again, so it doesn't really make sense to do it in the loop).  I would expect something like `$Word_Hash{$Word}++` to keep a count of how many times you've seen that word.  (You also need to loop through `@lines`, and `@lines` is actually `@words`.)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in your last sentence "(You also need to loop through '@lines', and '@lines' is actually '@words'." Could you please clarify with some examples?

Comment: Sure -- `@User_Input` is an array of lines.  That's what you get when you read all of a file into an array.  You're looping through lines and calling that `$Word`, which is a bit confusing.  You then split `$Word` on whitespace and put the results in `@lines`; those are the actual words, so I would call that array `@words`.  Then, to do something on each word, you need another `for` loop nested inside the ones you have, which iterates over the words (stored in `@lines` currently).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid slurping files when you don't need everything in memory, so your `@User_Input = <STDIN>;` is not a particularly good idea.  You can perfectly well process this all one line at a time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %words;

while (my $line = <>)
{
    foreach my $word (split /\s+/, $line)
    {
        $words{$word}++;
    }
}

foreach my $word (keys %words)
{
    print "$word: $words{$word}\n";
}
```

Sorting the data is a bit fiddlier, but can be done.

Comment: I'll observe that both `foreach` loops could be flattened into single-line operations (`$words{$_}++ foreach (split /\s+/, $line);` and `print "$_: $words{$_}\n" foreach (keys %words);`).  I tend to use a slight more verbose style.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, I was trying to group everything into one while loop I suppose. For future reference I will try to follow the model of breaking things down into chunks at a time.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lane '$X{$_}++ for(@F);END{for(keys %X){print $_." ".$X{$_}}}'
```

tested:

```
> echo "hello hello how are you you" | perl -lane '$X{$_}++ for(@F);END{for(keys %X){print $_." ".$X{$_}}}'
you 2
how 1
hello 2
are 1
>
```

Comment: other than 1 month, I looking for this  one-liner command. thank a lot man. and I modify to `perl -lane '$X{$_}++ for(@F); END { for(keys %X){ printf "%-.4d %s\n", $X{$_},$_ }}'`. Thanks again